# Block both the Russian Federation and Ukraine Countries from accessing my websites

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked before, but I want to know if there is a better more efficient way to block both the Russian Federation and Ukraine Countries from accessing my websites.

These countries are constantly ripping my website, using massive amounts of bandwidth, and and also providing BS porn related refer URLs to the sites. BTW... the Chinese are no better.

The following website provides a list if IP address for these countries so you can add them to the deny from ###.###.###.### in the .htaccess file.

The problem is that both the Russian Federation list has over 11,000 IP addresses and the Ukraine list has over 4,000 IP addresses.

This would mean adding about 15,000 deny from ###.###.###.### lines to the .htaccess file.

**Questions:**

(1) Would adding this many deny statements be inefficient, thus adding too much overhead to the Apache server because every hit would have to be looked up in the deny list?

(2) Is there a better more efficient way to do this?

BTW... a few of my important websites are built on the Drupal 6.x CMS system.

**Note: My websites are hosted on a shared server. Therefore I do not have access to the root or Apache system.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is better to do it at system level using iptables or csf firewall. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/ this should help

Comment: LogicIO, Thanks for the suggestion, but my websites are hosted on a shared server. I do not have access to the root or Apache system.

Comment: have you checked this out? https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ban

Comment: LogicIO, Thanks again. Yes, but it is not available for Drupal 6.x. It's only available for 7.x and 8.x CMS systems.